# check you grade using switch statements c++

Tags: c++

Actually, I do not from where to start. I faced this problem when I had Quiz in class that I had to figure out when the user Enter some Number of age, the result will show if that number is old, younger or a baby. I already know and kind of this will not work with "switch statements" very well and hard to write "case 0: ... case 100:". as I googled about this issue, but only work with "if/else statements". Guide me please if there any example code that uses with "switch statements" or just say keep doing with "if/else statements".

kindly regards

Here switch statements works bad.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
int age;

cout << "Enter your age: " << endl;
cin >> age;

switch (age) {

case 0:
        cout << "Young" << endl;
    break;

case 20:
        cout << "Middle" << endl;
    break;

case 70:
        cout << "Prime" << endl;
    break;

default:
    cout << "Invalid age" << endl;
}
cout << "Your age is " << age << endl;

 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

Here if/else statements and works well

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
int age;

cout << "Enter your age: " << endl;
cin >> age;

if (age >= 50) {
    cout << "Prime" << endl;//
}
else if (age >= 20) {
    cout << "Middle" << endl;//
}
else if (age >= 10) {
    cout << "Young" << endl;//
}

else {
    cout << "Baby" << endl;//

}

 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You are trying to make a switch statement into something it's not. You can't. Use a chain of if statements.

Comment: `switch` only works for discrete values.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to use a `switch` for something that works so much better if written as an `if` block?

Some compilers allow a *range-based* `switch` as a language extension (using a notation like `case 20...69:` , but that's rather pointless in my opinion, as all you end up with is non-portable code.

Always pick the correct tool for the job: you wouldn't put your clothes in a dishwasher would you?

Reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html

Comment: Apparently one may put their cloths in a dishwasher, provided it's a GNU dishwasher.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm sure there's a joke with the kitchen sink nearby.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to [the c++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/#switch):

> The syntax of the switch statement is a bit peculiar. Its purpose is to check for a value among a number of possible constant expressions. It is something similar to concatenating if-else statements, but limited to constant expressions.

You can not use wildcard syntax for the expressions. In a similiar piece of code that I found, the user input was first evaluated and assigned a letter from a to d. In the switch case, that letter gave the particular input.

You COULD stack the switch conditions like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void Main()
{
    int age; // User-input
    switch (age)
    {
        case 0:
        default:
            cout << "Invalid age." << endl;
            break;
        case 1:          
        case 2:
        case 3:
        // Continue until last age of "young" is reached.  
    } 
}
```

However, you can see how ghastly that would be.